# How best to test class that depends on constants in another file?

Tags: ruby, rspec, dependencies

I'm writing a Ruby library - call it `module MyLibrary` - which depends upon a data parser. The parser is specific to the library, but may need to be swapped out for a different parser at a later date, so it makes sense to have it be a class nested in `MyLibrary` - `class MyLibrary::Parser`.

`MyLibrary` exposes a few exception types to the client, and the `Parser` may hit situations where it wants to raise these exceptions (and `MyLibrary` is happy to pass them through). So I have the following arrangement:

my_library.rb:

```
require 'parser'
module MyLibrary
  class SomeException < RuntimeError
  end

  def self.do_it
    parser = Parser.new
    parser.parse_it
  end
end
```

parser.rb

```
module MyLibrary
 class Parser
   def parse_it
     if bad_stuff
       raise SomeException, "Argh"
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Now, I want to unit-test `Parser` using rspec.

parser_spec.rb

```
require 'parser'

RSpec.describe Parser do
  it 'raises when bad stuff happens' do
    expect { Parser.new.parse_it }.to raise_error(MyLibrary::SomeException)
  end
end
```

But because I'm unit-testing the `Parser` and my_library.rb hasn't been required in, `SomeException` isn't defined.

What's my best method for providing `SomeException` within `Parser`'s spec? Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

Comment: I think it depends on whether or not you really want this file `parser.rb` to be loadable as an atomic component. If you do, then you will need to move the `SomeException` definition to that file (or even make a separate file, `exceptions.rb` which you load anywhere you need it. That being said, I'm not sure "unit testing" _requires_ you to load each file atomically, and it's not something I choose to do.

Comment: @maxple - with the (possible) exception of this unit test, `parser.rb` never needs to be loaded separately from `my_library.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 things you could consider.

1. Building on maxple's comment, unless you have a specific reason for it, the `SomeException` class could just be defined in `parser.rb`. That class is the one raising the error, the spec test would work, and anyone requiring that file would have access to that exception. Since you don't even reference it in `my_library.rb` it seems like it would be fine. Another behavioral reason that supports this approach is if the error is a "Parsing" error, the exception name should reflect that and the `Parser` is the class that should own that. If the `MyLibrary` class is just forwarding any exception along, it doesn't matter what it is and it shouldn't be defined there.
2. If you want to keep the exception defined in `my_library.rb`, then I would suggest using a `spec_helper.rb` file, that lives in your `spec` folder, to load your full library. This is usually done by requiring your top level `lib/my_library.rb` file. Rspec commonly adds your top level lib folder to the ruby include path for just this purpose. Then each and every spec test file you write should `require 'spec_helper'`. In my experience this is probably the most idiomatic way to load all common dependencies for unit testing in rspec.

Comment: I think either of these would work. I was wanting to avoid defining `SomeException` in `parser.rb` because it may be swapped out at some point, and the replacement would need the same exceptions (so clients can still catch them). I was avoiding requiring `my_library.rb` into the `Parser` spec because `Parser` shouldn't depend on `MyLibrary`. _However_, since I know `Parser` won't ever be used without `MyLibrary`, that's probably the route to go.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't done much in rspec but wouldn't it help if you move the `require 'parser'` line from `my_library.rb` to `parser.rb`? The way I see it it's the Parser that needs that exception not the other way around.

Like I said my knowledge in this case is limited but I hope that will help, if not good luck in the search! :)

Comment: If I move the `require` to the `parser.rb`, then I would expect `MyLibrary` not to know about the `Parser`, which is a non-starter.